# Wrap icons around an extendable circle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I have a disc whose size can change, and some icons arranged around that disc. The icons should always be on the border of the disc, and the intervals between each icon should always stay the same.

Can this be done in pure css without having to compute each icon's position whenever the disc grows or shrinks?

Expected result:

```css
.container:nth-child(1)
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
}

.container:nth-child(2)
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.container > *
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle
{
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 20;
}

.icons
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 10;
}

.icons > *
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.container:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)
{
    transform: rotate(230deg) translate(150px) rotate(-230deg);
}

.container:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2)
{
    transform: rotate(217deg) translate(150px) rotate(-217deg);
}

.container:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(3)
{
    transform: rotate(204deg) translate(150px) rotate(-204deg);
}

.container:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(4)
{
    transform: rotate(191deg) translate(150px) rotate(-191deg);
}


.container:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(1)
{
    transform: rotate(230deg) translate(110px) rotate(-230deg);
}

.container:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2)
{
    transform: rotate(212deg) translate(110px) rotate(-212deg);
}

.container:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(3)
{
    transform: rotate(194deg) translate(110px) rotate(-194deg);
}

.container:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(4)
{
    transform: rotate(176deg) translate(110px) rotate(-176deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="icons">
        <span>A</span>
        <span>B</span>
        <span>C</span>
        <span>D</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="icons">
        <span>A</span>
        <span>B</span>
        <span>C</span>
        <span>D</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it programmatically, but only with CSS3. What you have to do is have an element inside it that takes the full width and can rotate, and then counterrotate the inner containers of those rotating elements.

So you would have to define the circles by using `:nth-child`. In order to achieve the correct effect and not apply a style twice, we will have to *count down* from our last element in order to only attract elements at a certain position. This is because `:nth-child(2n)` applies to `:nth-child(4n)` as well, which might create overlapping styles. Skip to the snippet if this seems a bit too complicated - it's actually quite simple.

So your basic HTML would be:

```
<wrapper> <!-- This is your disc -->
    <rotation> <!-- A rotation element. -->
       <counter> <!-- A counter-rotation element. This contains your content. -->
```

The first element has to have a position enabled. The second element needs to overlap with all the other secondary elements, so it needs a position of absolute, and the third element, well, that's up to you. It's just there to counter rotate it again.

Heres an implementation:

```css
/*The following animation shows that the outer frame is resizeable.*/
@-webkit-keyframes sizeBounce { 0% {width: 50vw; height: 50vw; }  50% {width: 20vw; height: 20vw; } 100% {width: 50vw; height: 50vw; }}
@keyframes sizeBounce { 0% {width: 50vw; height: 50vw; }  50% {width: 20vw; height: 20vw; } 100% {width: 50vw; height: 50vw; }}

div {
  position: relative;
  /* Any height you want here */
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  -webkit-animation: sizeBounce 2s infinite;
  animation: sizeBounce 2s infinite;
  
  /* You can do anything you want with this circle! */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

div > span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

div > span > em {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #dd0300;
  text-align: center;
}

div > span:nth-child(6n-6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
div > span:nth-child(6n-6) > em {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}

div > span:nth-child(6n-4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(60deg);
  transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
div > span:nth-child(6n-4) > em {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
}

div > span:nth-child(6n-3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(120deg);
  transform: rotateZ(120deg);
}
div > span:nth-child(6n-3) > em {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-120deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-120deg);
}

div > span:nth-child(6n-2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
div > span:nth-child(6n-2) > em {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}

div > span:nth-child(6n-1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(240deg);
  transform: rotateZ(240deg);
}
div > span:nth-child(6n-1) > em {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-240deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-240deg);
}
  
div > span:nth-child(6n) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(300deg);
  transform: rotateZ(300deg);
}
div > span:nth-child(6n) > em {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-300deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-300deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span><em>1</em></span>
  <span><em>2</em></span>
  <span><em>3</em></span>
  <span><em>4</em></span>
  <span><em>5</em></span>
  <span><em>6</em></span>
</div>
```

There is a way to automate this is SASS as well and it looks something like this:

```
@mixin rotatePiecemeally($pieces:6,$wrapper:span,$container:em){
    /* First calculate the angle between each piece */
    $degrees : 360 / $pieces;
    /* We want to count back from the amount of pieces to 0
     * The counting is because simple counting 2n, 3n, 4n, ... 
     * will result in 4n inheriting from 2n - to keep things clean,
     * we want to avoid that.  */
    @for $i from 0 through ($pieces - 1){
        & #{$wrapper}:nth-child(#{$pieces}n-#{$i}){
            transform: rotateZ(#{$i * $degrees}deg);
        }
        & #{$wrapper}:nth-child(#{$pieces}n-#{$i}) > #{$container}{
            transform: rotateZ(#{-$i * $degrees}deg);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it by doing the following:

```
#mycircle {
    @include rotatePiecemeally(6);
}
```

And you can optionally include which elements you want to use as the children. Don't forget they all need some absolute positioning for this to work. Don't forget to add any `prefixes` you need (I added them to the snippet because I am using Safari)

Comment: From what I gather SASS is a CSS compiler, not supported natively on any browser. Will SASS compute the positions on the run whenever the circle's size changes? Because that is what I am currently doing in JavaScript, but I'm looking for a CSS/CSS3 only alternative.

Comment: You can't do that as CSS never knows the amount of children by itself. You could, however, output a whole bunch of these with SASS, use the stylesheet and then trigger them with a class change. I've done that before and you get the enhancement of being fully CSS.

Comment: Also the CSS takes into account that the outer circle can change, so as long as you keep the same amount of elements inside it should work like a charm. I'll add a little animation to show what I mean :)

Comment: @notyourtype I added an animation that will scale the outer circle. It just shows that the outer circle can be any square size you want and this will work.

Comment: An interesting approach, however the circle can take any size it needs so that would result in a large number of classes to choose from.

Comment: @notyourtype I'm unsure what you mean here. By 'size', do you means _amount_ of icons? Or _size_ of circle?

Comment: I mean the radius of the circle.

Comment: @notyourtype The animation shows that the radius of the circle can be set in CSS to _any_ size you want. No need for classes.. I don't see your issue here. I have only predefined it because it _needs_ **a** definition. The animation is to show that it doesn't break when it resize - its the easiest way to quickly show multiple potential sizes.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the intervals between each icon equal as the circle stretches?

Comment: @notyourtype Well, you have control over the inner elements, don't you? You can make them have a percentage based size (say `span > em { width: 40$; height: 40%;}`), which will stretch them as the outer circle grows bigger. I'm sorry, but the snippet really covers a lot and it's only a matter of adjusting the sizes. Check it out, I made the change. **Also:** the intervals _are_ equal. Even if the icons don't resize.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to adapt your code and see if it works out for me.

Comment: @notyourtype I'd really suggest to at least try the preprocessor SASS code, Even though you compile it before upload, it's really efficient and stops you from having to write all those lines! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Without a preprocessor, I believe you'll need a script to achieve this. Here I've used jQuery in order to compute the intervals on hover.

**Note**

this would also support a dynamic number of `.circle` elements

```js
+ function() {
  var to;
  $(".wrap").on('mouseenter', function() {
    var circles = $(this).find(".circle");
    var degree = (2 * Math.PI) / circles.length; //calc delta angle
    var transforms = [];

    // Calculate the position for each circle
    circles.each(function(index) {
      var x = 100 * Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI + degree * (-1 * index - 0.5));
      var y = 100 * Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI + degree * (-1 * index - 0.5));

      transforms.push('translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)');
    });

    // Function to moves all the circles
    // We'll pop a circle each time and than call this function recursively
    function moveCircles() {
      var transform = transforms.shift();
      circles.css('transform', transform);

      circles.splice(0, 1);
      if (circles.length) to = setTimeout(moveCircles, 400);
    }

    moveCircles();
  });

  $(".wrap").on('mouseleave', function() {
    var circles = $(this).children().css('transform', '');
    clearTimeout(to);
  });
}();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
}
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.circle {
  transition: all 0.8s;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: calc(50% - 2px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent {
  transition: all 0.8s;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 8;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px black, inset 0 0 15px black, 0 0 15px black;
}
.parent:before,
.parent:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  height: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 22px;
  left: 12px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
.parent:before {
  top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 0 black;
}
.parent:hover:before,
.parent:hover:after {
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 0 none;
}
.wrap:hover .parent,
.wrap:hover .parent:before,
.wrap:hover .parent:after {
  background: darkgray;
}
.wrap:hover .parent:before {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.wrap:hover .circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px black, inset 0 0 15px black, 0 0 15px black;
}
.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.circle:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 8;
}
.circle:after,
button:after {
  transition: all 0.8s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 200%;
  z-index: 8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1);
}
.circle:hover:after,
button:hover:after {
  left: -200%;
  top: -50%;
}
.circle:hover:before {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px black, inset 0 0 15px black, 0 0 15px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/56729.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/54976.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">Just Text</div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/56582.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already have something similar in JavaScript, but I wondered if it was possible to do this in CSS only. Also my intent isn't to arrange all the icons to fill the space around the circle, but rather keep them together and fit the circle's border, as I illustrated in my original snippet.

Comment: @notyourtype: CSS wouldn't be designed for that. It's made for styling, and this definately falls more into the manipulation side of things. Sure, it can be done in CSS, but it would be slower, less efficient and would take longer to write than a js solution.